# Django Models Decimal quantize result has too many digits for current context

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, models

Until today i got my models like that:

```
class Ambiente1m(models.Model):
    Zona = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    Temperatura1 = models.IntegerField()
    Humedad1 = models.IntegerField()
```

But i tried to get Temperatura and Humedad as a Decimal (4,2) and adding 2 more columns to it:

```
class Ambiente1m(models.Model):
    Zona = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    Temperatura1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    Humedad1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    Temperatura2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    Humedad2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

Adding default values for Humedad -1 and 99.99 for Temperatura.

Then i used the python manage.py makemigrations, and migrate.
I get the following trace:

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, sessions, auth, SmartFICApp
Running migrations:
  Applying SmartFICApp.0017_auto_20170220_1830...Traceback (most recent call las           t):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.p           y", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.p           y", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",            line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",            line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/m           igrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py"           , line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_ini           tial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py"           , line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_           initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py"           , line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py           ", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec           t_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/f           ields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py           ", line 382, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py           ", line 145, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py           ", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.           py", line 1612, in get_db_prep_save
    self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/operation           s.py", line 493, in adapt_decimalfield_value
    return utils.format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", lin           e 200, in format_number
    value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".1") ** decimal_places, context=cont           ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 2469, in quantize
    'quantize result has too many digits for current context')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3873, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context
```

The problem is, i tried to get models.IntegerField() version:

```
class Ambiente1m(models.Model):
    Zona = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    Temperatura1 = models.IntegerField()
    Humedad1 = models.IntegerField()
    Temperatura2 = models.IntegerField()
    Humedad2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Im using PostgreSQL.

But i get the same error, *decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context* dont matter what i do, it doesn't work. I dont use any DecimalField in my code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe your database contains data that does not fit the constraints of your fields? It sounds like it...

Comment: I have truncated the tables.

Comment: Could you show the migration file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Django was trying to migrate an old version of migration file instead of the new one. I don't know why.

I have solved this editing that file with new customization and deleting the .pyc file forcing to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error, I noticed that the name is taken by many attributes of other models, so I tried to solve this problem by assigning different name of this attributes.
I think the problem is as said by @shaderlolz is there is some migrations doesn't applied correctly!

So changing the name of the attribute will put the spot at this attribute when making migration so:
Change the name of the attribute.
Apply necessary migrations.
And It will work without errors!